# Importar único CSV que contiene varios conjuntos de datos

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, importación

Primero os pongo un poco en contexto: Estoy haciendo un trabajo de la universidad sobre proteínas. Para ello nos tenemos que descargar un archivo de formato .gff con varias proteínas y, haciendo uso de Excel, convertirlo a .csv (las instrucciones del ejercicio nos obligan a hacerlo así). Haciendo esto, tengo un CSV con este formato:

[image: CSV]

En la foto se muestran 3 tablas, cada una de ellas representa una proteína diferente. La primera columna representa qué estructura tiene la proteína (hélice, lámina, transmembrana...). Las 2ª y 3ª columnas indican entre qué aminoácidos se dan esas estructuras (por ejemplo, en la primera proteína tenemos una estructura de "hélice" entre los aminoácidos 7 y 18). Al importar el archivo en R, tengo un .txt así:

---

##sequence-region P02633 1 79;;

Helix;7;18

Beta strand;20;22

Beta strand;26;28

Helix;29;39

Helix;40;42

Beta strand;45;48

Helix;50;57

Beta strand;58;60

Beta strand;62;65

Helix;67;77

##sequence-region Q35467 1 134;;

Transmembrane;33;53

Transmembrane;77;98

Transmembrane;113;133

##sequence-region P33763 1 92;;

Helix;4;20

Helix;31;39

Helix;52;59

Beta strand;63;68

Helix;69;85

---

Ahora viene mi problema: De aquí necesito extraer la información de cada una de las proteínas por separado. Según la profesora todo el CSV debe quedar en una única variable de nombre `proteinas`, y cuando yo ejecute

```
proteinas[Q35467]
```

R deberá devolver toda la información (supongo que con eso se refiere a imprimir en pantalla la tabla en cuestión) asociada a la proteína que lleva ese nombre (tanto en la foto como en el .txt se ve que ese nombre corresponde a la segunda proteína).

He intentado leer el csv de todas las formas que se me han ocurrido, os pongo aquí algunas de las formas que no he borrado (he hecho muchos intentos y en algunos he borrado cosas):

```
proteínas <- read_delim("./secuencias/secuencias.csv", delim = ";",
                 escape_double = FALSE, col_names = FALSE,
                 trim_ws = TRUE)
proteinas <- read.table("./secuencias/secuencias.csv", sep = ";", header = TRUE)
proteinas <- read.csv("./secuencias/secuencias.csv", col_types = cols(x=col_factor()), col_names = T)
```

De verdad, no sé qué más hacer, he mirado en StackOverflow en inglés y en español además de otras webs y aparece cómo unir varios csv en uno pero lo que yo quiero es lo contrario...

Os agradecería cualquier clase de sugerencia para sacar este ejercicio, ya que sin la información de esas proteínas no puedo continuar con el entregable...

Muchísimas gracias a todos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el archivo no es un CSV o digamos por partes es un CSV, por lo que habría que aislar esas partes para tratarlas como un archivo separado por comas. Lo que se me ocurre es:

1. Leer el archivo como un archivo de texto común
2. Hacer un `split()` para separar cada bloque de cada proteina
3. Iterar sobre cada bloque, para leer los datos como un CSV

Algo así:

```
# Leemos el archivo en una cadena 
TXT <- paste0(readLines(con = file('prueba.txt')), collapse = "\n")

# Dividimos por bloque de proteina
lista <- sapply(strsplit(TXT, '##'), strsplit, '\n')[-1]

# Por cada bloque leemos los datos
lapply(lista, FUN = function(x) {
  setNames(read.table(text=x[-1], sep=";"),
           c('Estructura', 'Aminoacido1', 'Aminoacido2'))
  }) -> proteinas

# Asignamos los nombres de proteinas
names(proteinas) <- sapply(lista, FUN = function(x) strsplit(x[1], " ")[[1]][2])

proteinas

$P02633
    Estructura Aminoacido1 Aminoacido2
1        Helix           7          18
2  Beta strand          20          22
3  Beta strand          26          28
4        Helix          29          39
5        Helix          40          42
6  Beta strand          45          48
7        Helix          50          57
8  Beta strand          58          60
9  Beta strand          62          65
10       Helix          67          77

$Q35467
     Estructura Aminoacido1 Aminoacido2
1 Transmembrane          33          53
2 Transmembrane          77          98
3 Transmembrane         113         133

$P33763
   Estructura Aminoacido1 Aminoacido2
1       Helix           4          20
2       Helix          31          39
3       Helix          52          59
4 Beta strand          63          68
5       Helix          69          85
```

Comment: Ha funcionado perfecto, incluso escribiendo

TXT <- paste0(readLines(con = file('prueba.csv')), collapse = "\n")

Como comentario para las demás personas que vean este hilo, para llamar a una proteína en concreto solo hay que escribir:

proteinas['P31151]

Muchas gracias!